# How to get code of color selected in Background in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicolor

How can I get code or anything about selected color to set it anywhere programmatically?

[image]

I'd like to get background-color information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get background color from UI object:

```
let color = label.backgroundColor
```

---

Set background color for UI object:

```
// green color for example
let color = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha 1.0)

label.backgroundColor = color
```

---

Get red, green, blue and alpha values from `UIColor`:

```
let color = label.backgroundColor

var red = CGFloat()    
var green = CGFloat()
var blue = CGFloat()
var alpha = CGFloat()

color!.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
```

Answer (score 1):

By getting UIView's `backgroundColor` [attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/backgroundColor):

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use code to retrieve the value you can click the blue icon (arrows) on the right and choose `other` at the bottom of the list. Then you'll be able to see the color's values in a variety of ways.